# Map generation algorithms

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, maps

I am currently working on a game in C# Xna, which works with (X,Y,Z) coordinates.
Each unit, contains some information about what is placed at that position, etc dirt, rock or nothing.
But I am pretty new into 3D game development, and I need some ideas for 3D map generation algorithms.
I thought of interpolation or perlin noise, but I would appreciate if someone would have some examples or ideas for which patterns to follow. By that I mean that first you would do perlin noise, then after you would do interpolation, and so on. Source codes would also be mostly appreciated :)

Comment: what kind of map are you trying to create? what about elevation, vegetation, water?

Comment: A simple map with mountains, hills, water and so on :) Somewhat like tundra vegetation, just with more hills ;)

Answer (score 6):

Use the real world! The United States Geological Survey (USGS) has a wonderful dataset of elevations worldwide. You can obtain it directly from the USGS at http://ned.usgs.gov/.

Comment: I wish I could favourite answers :)

Comment: usgs is very nice source, check out more elevation data sets at http://eros.usgs.gov/#/Find_Data/Products_and_Data_Available/Elevation_Products

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at existing projects such as [artificial terrain genererator](http://www.vterrain.org/Elevation/Artificial/)